# Modify HAPROXY's Stats Page

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I'm using HAProxy for load balancing and would like to make the stats page visible for certain people. I have already configured this to a point where the users must log into the website first and then under the status page of the site will load an iframe of HAProxy's status. However, I am wanting to remove the top portion of the page and just have the server statistics. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly in HA Proxy

```
stats enable
stats auth user:pass
stats uri     /haproxy-status
```

You can set whatever URI you wish.

You can find full details in

http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.3/doc/configuration.txt

Look near: stats auth :

Comment: This doesn't really get into modifying the stats page though. It's already enabled and working just fine, but I'm looking to change what is displayed. Their documentation does not really cover that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you dug into the source directory to see where the HTML lives?  You could just grep the source directory for some relevant phrases (i.e.: what it says on the stats page) and it'll turn up any files that contain them.  Then you can modify to your heart's content.  That's the most foolproof way.  Another way, though not recommended, is to fetch the stats page via AJAX using something like jQuery.  Then you can dynamically and programmatically remove the parts you don't want before inserting them into an iframe or div element.  I still say go with my first suggestion.